# appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert two "p" elements to a site to display two variable values.
But everytime i try to execute the Code i'm getting a **Uncaught TypeError: element.appendChild is not a function**.

Here is my js-Code

```
var wins = document.createElement('p');
var looses = document.createElement('p');
var nodeWins = document.createTextNode('hier variable einfügen');
var nodeLooses = document.createTextNode('hier variable einfügen2');
wins.appendChild(nodeWins);
looses.appendChild(nodeLooses);

var element = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');
element.appendChild(wins);
element.appendChild(looses);
```

Why doesn't this work?

I'm looking forward to answers and tipps.

Comment: because element is a HTMLCollection

Comment: `element[INDEX].appendChild(wins)`. Replace `[INDEX]` by the correct index of the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). So, if there is only a single element with the class `navbar` (which I am assuming is your intention) this should work:

```
element[0].appendChild(wins);
element[0].appendChild(looses);
```

Comment: Actually it will also work if there are more than a single element with the class navbar

Comment: @user1533609 thanks. I updated my answer to reflect my assumption of the original question's intention